# Theme Options page not showing up in admin menu

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, add-menu-page

I'm currently developing a WordPress theme and would like it to have a preferences pane in order to specify the user's Google Analytics tracking code for example.

Following the instructions I got on the Codex and multiple tutorials, this piece of code placed in the functions.php file should create a submenu of the 'Appearence' section and display either "Theme preferences" if the user has the 'manage_options' capability, or "You shall not pass." if not.

```
// Add theme settings link in the admin section menu

function add_appearance_menu() {
    add_theme_page('Theme preferences', 'Theme pref.', 'manage-options', 'interact-theme-settings', 'render_theme_settings');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_appearance_menu');

// Render theme settings page

function render_theme_settings() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    wp_die(__('You shall not pass.'));
    }
    echo "Theme preferences";
}
```

However, nothing new appears in my admin menu and when I try to access the page manually (http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/themes.php?page=interact-theme-settings), it displays this error message:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

...which in any way is not the "You shall not pass" message that I specified in my render-theme_settings() function.

Can someone please explain me what's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance for your help :)

EDIT: I would like to point out that -of course- the user I'm testing all this with HAS the 'manage_options' capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`manage-options` should be `manage_options`.
Try this:

```
 add_theme_page('Theme preferences', 'Theme pref.', 'manage_options', 'interact-theme-settings', 'render_theme_settings');
```

Comment: Ooooh gosh... I can be so dumb sometimes. Thanks a lot for your answer!